# Is it possible to change a text file to batch, execute it, and then revert it back to text in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

**Goal:** Write a powershell script to change a file from a `.txt` to `.bat`, execute the batch file and then convert it back to `.txt`.

**What I've tried:**

```
Write-Host "Renaming $($PatchPath)$($FileName) to LivePatch.bat"
Rename-Item "$($PatchPath)$($FileName)" "LivePatch.bat"

Write-Host "Running $($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat"
Start-Process "$($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat" 3>&1 2>&1 > "$($PatchPath)\results.txt"

Write-Host "Returning $($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat to it's original name: $($FileName)."
Rename-Item "$($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat" "$($FileName)"
```

Where `$PatchPath = "D:\Patches\"` and `$FileName = "LivePatch.txt`.

**Problem:**
This converts the file to batch, as I can see from looking at explorer during runtime, but when it tries to execute it, it returns the following:

```
'"D:\Patches\LivePatch.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've checked and made sure I can execute batch scripts like I'm attempting to above with batch scripts that already exist and that works fine.

**Old working solution:**
This is the batch script I've been using for this purpose, that this powershell script is supposed to replace:

```
REM rename %PatchPath%%FileName% "LivePatch.bat"
rename %PatchPath%%FileName% "LivePatch.bat"
REM Run Live Patch file %PatchPath%LivePatch.bat
REM call %PatchPath%LivePatch.bat > "%PatchPath%results.txt" 2>&1 
call %PatchPath%LivePatch.bat > "%PatchPath%results.txt" & type "%PatchPath%results.txt"

rename "%PatchPath%LivePatch.bat" "%FileName%"
```

Comment: use call operator `&` to call your batch script

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just make a copy of the .txt file with the suffix .bat, execute that, and then delete the copy?

Comment: You have race condition here. You can rename file back to `.txt` before `cmd` actually read it.

Comment: I've put a 1 second sleep between the renaming and the execution and that solves the problem, is this bad practice?

Answer (score -1):

Rather than rely on a sleep as you mentioned I would test if the file exists first.

```
Write-Host "Renaming $($PatchPath)$($FileName) to LivePatch.bat"
Rename-Item "$($PatchPath)$($FileName)" "LivePatch.bat"

if([System.IO.File]::Exists("$($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat")){ 
    Write-Host "Running $($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat"
    Start-Process "$($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat" 3>&1 2>&1 > "$($PatchPath)\results.txt"

    Write-Host "Returning $($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat to it's original name: $($FileName)."
    Rename-Item "$($PatchPath)LivePatch.bat" "$($FileName)"
}
```